# Differential Drive Control Techniques

Tags: mobile-robot, control, pid, differential-drive

I have a mobile robot that has a differential drive technique. I try to control the robot with PID controller. Is the best way for controlling differential drive robots?

If I want to compare different control techniques for this robot, which techniques do I search for?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* bb0667, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: First you should have applied your questions to a web search. Both your phrases "is pid the best control for differential drive robot" and "robot control techniques" turn up good hits.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this easily is with a constant step controller.  It's a controller that looks at the error and then just adds (or subtracts) a constant amount (usually very small).  It's very easy to implement.  However, it is slow to reach the desired velocity.  This can be mitigated with a feed forward mechanism; when starting from 'stopped' calculate the initial control value (throttle pwm value) based on measured values for stall throttle (the throttle (pwm value) below which the motor will not turn; so this also corresponds to the minimum possible non-zero velocity).  Given the target velocity, you can do a linear interpolation between min and max velocity to estimate the feed forward value for throttle.  Then the constant step controller will converge quickly from a standing start.  If there is a large perturbation while moving it will still respond slowly.

This differential drive robot uses a feed forward constant step controller for speed control and a constant step controller for heading control during goal to goal behavior.  https://github.com/Ezward/Esp32CameraRover2  Speed control is here https://github.com/Ezward/Esp32CameraRover2/blob/3cb95bc326873d1e354887132699924332c0c7e8/src/wheel/drive_wheel.cpp#L323, kinematic pose estimation is here https://github.com/Ezward/Esp32CameraRover2/blob/3cb95bc326873d1e354887132699924332c0c7e8/src/rover/rover.cpp#L313, and heading controller is here https://github.com/Ezward/Esp32CameraRover2/blob/3cb95bc326873d1e354887132699924332c0c7e8/src/rover/goto_goal.cpp#L333  Here an example of it in operation https://youtu.be/TjE9ceNOTJE

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Step controller is the easy way for this. You're right. But it's not the best solution. I just want to ask here. Doesn't the step controller's response delay the axiom time in the wheel? Or does it not respond to the system later than PID? @Ezward

Comment: Also, your robot is pretty good.

Comment: It does respond slower.  The feed forward helps considerably when starting from stop.  The robot I am using it on is for education, so as an intro to closed loop speed control the step controller is very easy to understand and implement and calibrate.